# Looking for help exporting from Blender to Google Earth

Tags: python, scripting, export

I've been trying to export models from Blender to Google Earth and I'm having some trouble.  I've tried using this script but it's written for an older version of Blender:

http://ynniv.com/blog/2006/03/blending-kml.html

I've also tried exporting the model as a Collada (.dae) file and using Add-->Model in Google Earth, but that doesn't seem to work for models with a large number of verts.

Ideally, I'd like to export from Blender directly to a KML/KMZ file without a lot of extra work or conversion.  It would also be nice to be able to tie the origin point in Blender to a lat/long/elevation as the script above does as well as select certain objects for export (since I don't need the camera, lamp, or empties to show up in Google Earth).

Has anyone been able to successfully do this?

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9SFKA4s7Vc) suggests using sketchup.

Comment: I don't have a problem going from Google Earth to Blender, my problem is going the other direction from Blender to Google Earth.  Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm facing same problem now.

Comment: No, still haven't figured it out.